# modify select2 style so that search bar is immediately searchable on click

Tags: jquery-select2

For the most part, [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#single-select-boxes) does I want it to. It provides me with a searchable dropdown list; however one glaring issue is that I need to click on the widget, then click in again to get to the search bar. This is different from other searchable dropdowns like [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-selection), where you can click on the widget and immediately start typing. Does anyone know if this result can be achieved with Select2? It's a great library otherwise and I'd hate to have to refactor it out.
[The linked image shows how my select2 widget is implemented. What I want is for the search bar to appear at the top, where the dashes are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BFfi.png)